# Mysql query regarding data comparison between two table

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have two tables namely `tblteacher` and `tblattendance`. I want to find the teacher who marked attendance on particular date. Say, on 2013-07-02. If the teacher's name exists on the table, `tblteacher`  it should show yes as status and no if it isn't.

```
SELECT distinct tblteacher.tshortname
    FROM tblteacher
    LEFT JOIN tblattendance
    ON tblteacher.tshortname = tblattendance.tshortname
    WHERE tblattendance.attdate = '2013-07-02';
```

I got common data on particular date. But how to fix status...

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
SELECT IF(t.tshortname IS NOT NULL,'yes','no')
  FROM  tblattendance AS a
  LEFT JOIN tblteacher AS t
  USING (tshortname)
  WHERE a.attdate = 20130702;
```

Comment: i am not getting perfect result out of it as it is not showing 'no' on the row where data is not matching betwwen two table..it showing only those data which are present on tblattendance

Comment: Could you edit your question so that it contains some sample data and the result you'd like to get? That will make it easier to ansewr the quesiton.

Comment: i have added database snapshot

Comment: @Ashish: please add some sample data

Answer (score 0):

You should use RIGHT JOIN. As explained [in mysql doc reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), if you join tables A and B, it still returns rows from table A, if there are no matching rows in table B.

```
SELECT t.shortname, CASE WHEN a.tshortname IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END as marked_attendance
  FROM  tblteacher t 
  RIGHT JOIN tblattendance a
  USING (tshortname)
  WHERE a.attdate = '2013-07-02';
```

Comment: i am not getting the data which isn't lie on tblattendance as status 'no'